# Sylow p-subgroup of order p does not normalize any other Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $P_1,P_2$ be distinct Sylow p-subgroups of $G$ with order $p$.

Is it generally true that $P_1$ cannot normalize $P_2$?

I've seen algebra textbooks use this fact for $p=3,11$ and they quote 'a consequence of Sylow's Theorem' yet I cannot see how this can hold. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's true that no Sylow $p$-subgroup can normalize a different one (though particular elements can normalize both, not every element can). This is because a Sylow subgroup is normal in its normalizer and therefore is the only subgroup of that order in the normalizer (by the fact that all Sylow subgroups for the same prime are conjugate).

Specializing to your problem, if any nonidentity  element in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p$ normalized a different Sylow $p$-subgroup, then every element would because every nonidentity element is a generator. Therefore this can't happen.

Answer (score 3):

A standard argument is:

Suppose $P$ is a $p$-Sylow group, and  $Q$ is a group of order a $p$-power, normalizing $P$. Then $PQ$ is also group (because $Q$ normalizes $P$), which contains $P$, and has order a power of $p$. Hence, $PQ = P$, since $P$ is maximal with that property. Therefore $Q$ is a subgroup of $P$.

In particular, the only $p$-Sylow group to normalize $P$ is $P$ itself.

Comment: Why should $PQ$ have order a power of $p$?

Comment: @MattSamuel Hi! Honesty in publishing, ha-ha: it's in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I, page 81 in my copy - I just looked it up. In any event, I'm sure I wrote 'standard argument' above because I learnt the fact from the book when I took the relevant course 2000 years ago... The observation there (a bit nicer than I had thought of just now) is that  $PQ/ P = Q / (Q \cap P)$, both sides making sense because $Q$ normalizes $P$. Thanks for the question though - it was sloppy of me not to be more complete.